# VB.net : 2 picture Boxes disappear but the third wont

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

Ok so this Is basically supposed to turn the visibility of the picture box to false if their health is below zero. Health is declared with all the other variables at the beginning. Two enemies always disappear when their health is zero, but one always keeps going. The code for their movement, health, etc is identical. Any suggestions?

```
    If zombie1health < 0 Then

        zombie1.Visible = False

    ElseIf zombie2health < 0 Then

        zombie2.Visible = False

    ElseIf zombie3health < 0 Then

        zombie3.Visible = False

    ElseIf zombie1.Visible = False And zombie2.Visible = False And zombie3.Visible = False Then

        zlblnext.Visible = True
        zbtnnext.Visible = True
        zbtnnext.Enabled = True

    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `if` - `ElseIf` when you should probably be using only `if` statements.

The code you are using will only hide all 3 zombies if they die in the order  3, 2 and 1.

Changing it to separated `Ifs` may solve your problem.

```
If zombie1health < 0 Then
    zombie1.Visible = False
End if

If zombie2health < 0 Then
    zombie2.Visible = False
End if

If zombie3health < 0 Then
    zombie3.Visible = False
End if

If zombie1.Visible = False And zombie2.Visible = False And zombie3.Visible = False Then

    zlblnext.Visible = True
    zbtnnext.Visible = True
    zbtnnext.Enabled = True

End If
```

Comment: i tried that but thank you. maybe its because it's in the timer tick sub.

Comment: Try changing the Zombie#health < 0 to Zombie#health <= 0, and make sure its life is becoming zero.